# Plotting pandas aggregated objects

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I've obtained an aggregate in the following form:

```
                                                        measure
                                                            mean
attribute dataset_name                          method            
50      d111                                  m1        0.559120
                                              m2        0.632573
                                              m3        0.555867
                                              m4        0.587053
                                              m5        0.647413
        d222                                  m1        0.759120
                                              m2        0.632573
                                              m3        0.655867
                                              m4        0.584053
                                              m5        0.647413
        d333                                  m1        0.859120
                                              m2        0.632573
                                              m3        0.655867
                                              m4        0.587053
                                              m5        0.647413
```

My goal is to plot this data in the following manner:

```
x axis = attribute

y axis = mean

hue = method

facet_wrap = dataset_name
```

I cant seem to get this working with pandas + seaborn library. I mostly have problems with getting this table to a melted version, pivotted on dataset_name, method and attribute..

Thank you!

Comment: Show us your code please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need select column `measure` for avoid `MultiIndex` and then [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.reset_index().columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['measure', 'method', 'dataset_name', 'attribute'], ['mean', '']],
           labels=[[3, 2, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

---

```
df1 = df['measure'].reset_index()
print (df1)
    attribute dataset_name method      mean
0          50         d111     m1  0.559120
1          50         d111     m2  0.632573
2          50         d111     m3  0.555867
3          50         d111     m4  0.587053
4          50         d111     m5  0.647413
5          50         d222     m1  0.759120
6          50         d222     m2  0.632573
7          50         d222     m3  0.655867
8          50         d222     m4  0.584053
9          50         d222     m5  0.647413
10         50         d333     m1  0.859120
11         50         d333     m2  0.632573
12         50         d333     m3  0.655867
13         50         d333     m4  0.587053
14         50         d333     m5  0.647413

print (df1.columns)
Index(['attribute', 'dataset_name', 'method', 'mean'], dtype='object')
```

and for plot use [`Manish Saraswat' answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49066416/2901002).

Comment: hi @jezrael, can you please check this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49067073/how-to-append-two-or-more-dataframes-in-pandas-and-do-some-analysis

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @jezrael answer, this is for the plotting:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col='dataset_name', hue='method',size = 7, aspect = 1.0)
(g.map(plt.scatter, 'attribute','mean').set_titles("{col_name} Dataset").add_legend())

# output plot
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I solved it in a more clumsy way, this is great!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by simply doing:

```
df_new = df.reset_index()
```

If there is any more elegant way I would be glad to know.

Comment: There is not Multiindex in columns? What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Yes, this is a multi index