# how to append two or more dataframes in pandas and do some analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have 3 df's:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"Name":["one","two","three"],"value":[4,5,6]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({"Name":["four","one","three"],"value":[8,6,2]})
df3=pd.DataFrame({"Name":["one","four","six"],"value":[1,1,1]})
```

I can append one by one but I want to append all the three data frames at a time and do some analysis.

I am trying to count the name contains in how many data frame divided by total dataframes `name present in dataframes/total dataframes`

My desired output is,

```
 Name  value   Count
 one    11      1
 two    5       0.333
 three  8       0.666
 four   9       0.666
 six    1       0.333
```

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: try this for first half,
df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
df.groupby(["Name"])["value"].sum().reset_index()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- first [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)
- aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html)
- divide column

---

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
df = pd.concat(dfs)

df1 = df.groupby('Name')['value'].agg([('value', 'sum'), ('Count', 'size')]).reset_index()
df1['Count'] /= len(dfs)
```

Similar solution:

```
df1 = (pd.concat(dfs)
         .groupby('Name')['value']
         .agg([('value', 'sum'), ('Count', 'size')])
         .assign(Count = lambda x: x.Count /len(dfs))
         .reset_index())

print (df1)
    Name  value     Count
0   four      9  0.666667
1    one     11  1.000000
2    six      1  0.333333
3  three      8  0.666667
4    two      5  0.333333
```

Comment: @pyd - Glad can help!