# How to difference of two dataframes except one column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, standard-deviation

I have two data frames with same column names.

```
         wave   num   stlines      fwhm        EWs  MeasredWave
 0    4050.32   3.0  0.282690  0.073650  22.160800  4050.311360
 1    4208.98   5.5  0.490580  0.084925  44.323130  4208.973512
 2    4374.94   9.0  0.714830  0.114290  86.964970  4374.927110
 3    4379.74   9.0  0.314040  0.091070  30.442710  4379.760601
 4    4398.01  14.0  0.504150  0.098450  52.832360  4398.007473
 5    4502.21   8.0  0.562780  0.101090  60.559960  4502.205220


         wave  num   stlines      fwhm        EWs  MeasredWave
 0    4050.32  3.0  0.276350  0.077770  22.876240  4050.310469
 1    4208.98  5.5  0.493035  0.084065  44.095755  4208.974363
 2    4374.94  6.0  0.716760  0.111550  85.111070  4374.927649
 3    4379.74  1.0  0.299070  0.098400  31.325300  4379.759339
 4    4398.01  6.0  0.508810  0.084530  45.783740  4398.004164
 5    4502.21  9.0  0.572320  0.100540  61.252070  4502.205764
```

As the both the dataframes have column names and column one `wave` is same in both the dataframes. I want to take the difference of all the column except column 1 i.e, `wave`.

So, the resultant dataframe should have column1 and the difference of all the other columns

how can i do that?

Comment: If you would like to get fast and good answer, make other user life easy. Clean your code, make it as short as possible, don't add links to your local folder with your files, etc. Additionally ask one issue in a quistion

Comment: There are same columns names and same number of rows in both df?

Comment: yes both column names and rows are exactly the same.!

Comment: So need subtract all columns values without first?

Comment: yeah exactly.! @jezrael

Comment: One more question? How can i take average and stardard deviation of multiple dataframes with unequal number of rows in pandas? similarly keeping the column 'wave'asexception?? @jezrael

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar - Not so easy answer, but I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49067231/2901002) should help.

Comment: yeah it worked. Thanks alot man. @jezrael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need extract columns names by [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html) and then use [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
cols = df1.columns.difference(['wave'])
#is possible specify multiple columns
#cols = df1.columns.difference(['wave','MeasredWave'])

#df1[cols] = means in output are not touch columns from df1
df1[cols] = df1[cols].sub(df2[cols])
print (df1)
      wave  num   stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave
0  4050.32  0.0  0.006340 -0.00412 -0.715440     0.000891
1  4208.98  0.0 -0.002455  0.00086  0.227375    -0.000851
2  4374.94  3.0 -0.001930  0.00274  1.853900    -0.000539
3  4379.74  8.0  0.014970 -0.00733 -0.882590     0.001262
4  4398.01  8.0 -0.004660  0.01392  7.048620     0.003309
5  4502.21 -1.0 -0.009540  0.00055 -0.692110    -0.000544
```

---

```
cols = df1.columns.difference(['wave'])
#df2[cols] = means in output are not touch columns from df2
df2[cols] = df1[cols].sub(df2[cols])
print (df2)
      wave  num   stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave
0  4050.32  0.0  0.006340 -0.00412 -0.715440     0.000891
1  4208.98  0.0 -0.002455  0.00086  0.227375    -0.000851
2  4374.94  3.0 -0.001930  0.00274  1.853900    -0.000539
3  4379.74  8.0  0.014970 -0.00733 -0.882590     0.001262
4  4398.01  8.0 -0.004660  0.01392  7.048620     0.003309
5  4502.21 -1.0 -0.009540  0.00055 -0.692110    -0.000544
```